# chosen jquery library not loading - is not a function error

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to load the chosen library: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

I am enqueuing a .js file as below:

```
wp_register_script( 'js_custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.js', false );
wp_enqueue_script ( 'js_custom' );
```

Inside the .js file I loading chosen like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.chzn-select').chosen();
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Result of expression 'jQuery(".chosen").chosen' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: What is in `js/jquery.js`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to load chosen library:

```
wp_register_script( 'js_chosen', 'https://raw.github.com/harvesthq/chosen/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.js', array('jquery') );
wp_register_script( 'js_custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.js', array('jquery', 'js_chosen') );
wp_enqueue_script ( 'js_custom' );
```

Comment: FYI to people who try the above. Chosen uses coffee script now so that link doesn't lead to anywhere. Also, when serving files from github try http://rawgit.com/ as raw.github.com doesn't always work well. Or use something like cdnjs.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but for anyone else reading this question, don't use github as it won't work.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Add JQuery Chosen Quickly
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85824/
 * Description: Test/Add chosen to site without adding any files
 * Version: 1.0
 */

function enqueue_chosen_jquery() {
    wp_register_style( 'chosencss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css', false, '1.1.0', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'chosenjs', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chosencss' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chosenjs' );
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_chosen_jquery' );

// Assuming jQuery is loaded in the head
function chosen_jquery_inline() {
if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $( ".chzn-select" ).chosen();
    });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'chosen_jquery_inline', 999 );
```

Comment: For most recent CDN links check http://cdnjs.com/libraries/chosen