# Wordpress site hamburger menu toggle not working

Tags: plugins, menus, themes, javascript, navigation

When I shrink down the browser to test for mobile responsiveness, the hamburger menu does not open, even after I clicked on it. I have tried everything from troubleshooting my plugins to searching all the questions on these forums. How do I fix it? Please help. I am attaching a picture of the piece of code in question and the link to the website.

www.mmisc.com/politalkapp

[image]

Comment: Can you include the jQuery code relating to this.  This could be an issue anywhere from 'another element overlapping the hamburger icon' to 'the jQuery isn't firing'.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I am new to this. How do I upload a jQuery file? How do I download this file from Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the jQuery you've used, I can't recommend a fix but currently this is where your issue lies:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function
```

Thats taken from console log -> jquery.usp.core.js

Looks like someone else has had this problem by missing out a required library, check out:

[chosen jquery library not loading - is not a function error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85824/chosen-jquery-library-not-loading-is-not-a-function-error)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please write a comment instead of an answer if you're only adding hints for debugging :)

Comment: @sven Sure but with including the console error along with another link I thought it would be unclear in a comment but will do

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I am new to this. How do I upload a jQuery file? How do I download this file from Wordpress?